# Assembly code that works for gcc but not for clang

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, clang

I got this code working using gcc compiler for arm arch `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c s.s`.

```
.arch armv6-m
.thumb_func
MOVS  r0, lr
MOVS  r1, #0xF
AND   r0, r1
```

and when I try to assemble it using clang for arm arch `clang --target=arm-none-abi -c s.s` I got these errors

```
s.s:3:13: error: invalid operand for instruction
MOVS  r0, lr
            ^
s.s:5:1: error: invalid instruction
AND   r0, r1
^
```

I tried to disassemble the working gcc output I found it converted MOVS to MOV and AND to ANDS

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -S s.o

s.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr
   2:   210f        movs    r1, #15
   4:   4008        ands    r0, r1
```

so I changed the code to be like the assembled one and rerun the clang again and it passed fine but when I reran gcc I got this error

```
s.s:5: Error: instruction not supported in Thumb16 mode -- `ands r0,r1'
```

1. Why is this instruction not supported although the gcc assembler changed it from AND to ANDS and worked before? and clang accepts it?
2. Also why the gcc assembler changed MOVS to MOV?
3. How to get a common code that works for the both compilers?

Comment: try mov instead of movs

Comment: assembly language is specific to to the tool gnu assembler and gcc are different, clang is yet another. no reason to expect any kind of compatibility.   then pile on that arms mistake with the unified syntax making it all a big mess how different tools attempted to sorta support that (they have no requirement to support it in anyway much less arms documented syntax).

Comment: As per clang site, I thought clang is fully compatible with gcc even with the assembler! https://clang.llvm.org/

Comment: Well seems like you proved that wrong.  Wait I dont see assembly language mentioned on that page, this is assembly language not C.  It is mangled through a C front end, but it is not C.

Comment: Sounds like you are saying you needed to also file a bug with llvm before coming to SO to ask this question.  What did they say when you filed the bug with clang/llvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM unified syntax `.syntax unified` solved the ANDS unsuported instruction in Thumb16 mode, gcc error. As per [gnu binutils documents](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet.html#ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet), The unified syntax has this feature: All instructions set the flags if and only if they have an s affix.

so the final common code that works for gcc and clang is:

```
.arch armv6-m
.syntax unified
.thumb_func

MOV  r0, lr
MOVS r1, #0xF
ANDS r0, r1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.arch armv6-m
.thumb
mov r0,lr

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr
```

(clang built for armv6-m)

```
clang test.s -c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr
```

But with movs

```
.arch armv6-m
.thumb
movs r0,lr

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr
```

(goes back to first thumb support, assembler is free to do what they want)

```
clang test.s -c -o test.o
test.s:4:1: error: invalid instruction, any one of the following would fix this:
movs r0,lr
^
test.s:4:9: note: operand must be an immediate in the range [0,255]
movs r0,lr
        ^
test.s:4:9: note: operand must be a register in range [r0, r7]
movs r0,lr
        ^
```

and now this

```
.arch armv6-m
.thumb
.syntax unified
movs r0,lr

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:5: Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `movs r0,lr'
```

(only because this is armv6-m not armv7-m)

```
clang test.s -c -o test.o
test.s:5:1: error: invalid instruction, any one of the following would fix this:
movs r0,lr
^
test.s:5:9: note: operand must be an immediate in the range [0,255]
movs r0,lr
        ^
test.s:5:9: note: operand must be a register in range [r0, r7]
movs r0,lr
```

and this

```
.arch armv6-m
.thumb
.syntax unified
mov r0,lr

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr

clang test.s -c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr
```

your code

```
.arch armv6-m
.thumb_func
movs r0,lr

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4670        mov r0, lr
```

Again bad taste, but assembler can do what they want.

I stand corrected .thumb_func interestingly does something here

```
.arch armv6-m
movs r0,lr
```

makes no sense, but oh well...

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:3: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `movs r0,lr'
```

Hmm...

```
.arch armv6-m
mov r0,lr

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c test.s -o test.o
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:3: Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- `mov r0,lr'
```

Nope.

Comment: Before starting any assembly language you need both the processor documentation and the assembler documentation.  What part of the arm documentation did you not understand?

Comment: I'm not written any assembly code, I was porting a C application to to be compiled with clang. This small assembly code was inlined in the application and I faced this issue then!

Comment: assembly is assembly you want to mess with it, get the docs.  was this code you found for armv7-m and not armv6-m?  SO is not here to read the docs for you.  As soon as you saw the tools output the next step is to look up the instruction.  or contact the author.

Comment: When you contacted the author of this code you are using what did they say?

Comment: It's armv6-m as it runs on arm cortex 0, and author left!

Comment: So step two is to look up the error then look up the instruction.  disassemble the gcc code see what the isntruction is and compare that to the arm documentation.  clang is pretty crappy in their documentation as well as use of their tools, I will admit, but still, what did you see when you did that step?

Comment: If you are relying on this code for some reason then you need to own the code, C and assembly.  C doesnt port very well either esp with how folks misuse it with microcontrollers.  You need to own it all even the assembly language.

Comment: Yes the cortex-m0 and cortex-m0+ are based on the armv6-m architecture.  the code may have been written for armv7-m and then re-used on armv6-m.  It is not technically a bug, it simply isnt portable and for assembly language that is just how things are.  (same for C these days but thats another story)

Comment: MOV already works! I wrote that in the question, you can check it back, the blocking issue so far is AND and ANDS instructions.

Comment: Gcc converts AND to ANDS in a successful assembling operation but when I write ANDS in the code, gcc complains it is not supported! This is the issue I'm checking now